# search view using 2 different lists in android

Tags: android, android-studio, search, searchview

I have 2 custom listviews.

Its the kind of follow and unfollow options. When user writes anything in the searchView it should search in "list1" and if user clicks button named "follow" for multiple rows then those rows should be add to list2.

So searchView should basically work like search from list1 and if user selects rows then it should add to list2.

I don't have any idea if its possible to make it like this.

Comment: fix grammar and formatted text

Comment: Can you show your ui? So I can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can implement onClick on your custom list1. Then add the data from list1 to data model of list2 then refresh the adapter for list2.

I think you better use recyclerView instead of listView also.